# Security concerns with using Stripe checkout over Cordova

Tags: security, cordova, stripe-payments

I'm looking into using Stripe.js for payment processing in a mobile web application wrapped in Cordova.  According to the Stripe documentation all checkout pages should be served over https.  Since Cordova will technically be serving these pages locally in a webview, are there any security concerns I should worry about?

Note: I will still be using https to submit the tokenized card details from Stripe to my remote API server to actually complete the charge.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'm an engineer at Stripe.

Cordova/PhoneGap isn't a platform we actively support with Stripe.js, but after talking it over with the team, we have two suggestions for how to mitigate potential vulnerabilities:

1. Configure your [Domain Whitelist](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) sensibly, to limit the possibility of other scripts maliciously sending payment data to an untrusted third party. You should only need to add `https://api.stripe.com` to support communicating with Stripe.
2. Always load the latest version of Stripe.js from our servers, per the [Stripe.js documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js). This will ensure that you're always up-to-date with any bugfixes and patches we add to Stripe.js

Beyond that, I believe your exposure is similar to using Stripe.js in a normal webpage, loaded in-browser.

(I should note that I assume you're using Stripe.js and not Stripe Checkout—the latter would  require the `https://checkout.stripe.com` domain to be added to the domain whitelist, as well.)

Comment: Wow wasn't expecting to get someone from Stripe, thanks for your excellent reply!  This is along the lines of what I was thinking, I will be sure to implement the whitelisting.

Answer (score 1):

I posted an answer related to this in a similar question. If you control a custom API, give it https protection and send your whole checkout form down into an iframe (source set to your API endpoint).

Then use a plugin like [Cordova-HTTP](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP) for SSL pinning, and you should be more secure!

Original answer:
[Implement Stripe Payment Gateway in Cordova/Phonegap Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205200/implement-stripe-payment-gateway-in-cordova-phonegap-application/38547424#38547424)