# Implement Stripe Payment Gateway in Cordova/Phonegap Application

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, stripe-payments

Searched a lot. I want to integrate Stripe Payment Gateway in my cordova application is there any way to achieve it in android and ios using javascript.

Answer (score 4):

I emailed stripe, and apparently it works fine on iOS if you simply integrate it as you would on the web. Unfortunately it does not work on android yet! :(

> While Checkout should work fine on iOS devices with PhoneGap (or anything that uses native WebViews), it does not work on Android devices with native WebViews. This is a known issue, and one we would like to fix in the future, but are not able to fix yet. The solution, for now, if Android is a requirement is to build a custom form using Stripe.js[0].

<s>UPDATE:</s>

Apparently one exists! I haven't tried it yet but here's the link

http://plugins.telerik.com/plugin/stripe

<s>UPDATE 2: checkout.js actually works fine with phonegap or cordova now. Check out the docs [here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout).</s>

UPDATE 3: Apparenly checkout.js is broken again for anything over and including cordova ios 4.0.0, the latest version of cordova ios that works is 3.9.2. Got another question going on here about it: [Using Stripe Checkout with Cordova ios 4.0.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40296282/using-stripe-checkout-with-cordova-ios-4-0-0)

UPDATE 4: We are now using [Stripe V3 Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart) but stripe checkout.js should work as long as you have whitelisted stripe as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45697704/1624255)

Comment: What specifically breaks in an Android webview?

Comment: Not sure, that reply was straight from stripe. We're actually working on getting a plugin made.

Comment: @AmritKahlon will the plugin be an open-source Android Cordova plugin? Do you have a link to a repo if it exists?

Comment: @AlexanderWallaceMatchneer yea for sure. I'll post it here when it gets started

Comment: @AmritKahlon I'm after a solution to use Checkout from an Android webview, how did you get on?

Comment: @Newmania Are you using Phonegap? Their checkout.js works fine with it.

Comment: @AmritKahlon We are using Appgyver Steroids (built on Phonegap). We got it working with Checkout with a couple of tweaks, which I put here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904149/using-stripe-mobile-checkout-in-a-webview-payments-in-kik

Comment: Just for the record, if Apple/Google find out that you are charging through your app and not using apple in-app purchases, your app will be removed from the store.

Comment: @bertmaclin that only applies to virtual goods. Stripe is fine for selling goods and/or services that exist outside of your app.

Comment: @AmritKahlon have you made this plugin? It is a year and a half later, hoping you have something that works with iOS and Android!

Comment: Hey @GregoryMagarshak I am simply using stripe v3 elements now https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js and they work great. Just make sure to whitelist stripe

Answer (score 1):

Edit 2:

My below proposal hasn't worked, checkout.js gives me an error saying something went wrong, and to try a different browser. I still don't have a situation besides building my own checkout form.

Edit 1:

Proposed solution and how I am solving this:

In order to address this part of the [checkout.js docs](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) (seen in the FAQ at the bottom):
Proposed solution:

In order to address this part of the [checkout.js docs](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) (See the FAQ at the bottom),

> "All submissions of payment info using Checkout are made via a secure **HTTPS** connection. However, in order to protect yourself from certain forms of man-in-the-middle attacks, you must serve the page containing the payment form over **HTTPS** as well. In short, the address of the page containing Checkout must start with **https://** rather than just http://."

To secure this, I am embedding an `<iframe>` in my Cordova app with the `src` set to an API endpoint I've made and I own. The API endpoint returns the `<Form>` snipper they show in the Simple implementation in the docs. So my api endpoint returns this HTML:

```
<form action="/charge" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh"
    data-amount="2000"
    data-name="Stripe.com"
    data-description="2 widgets"
    data-image="/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto">
  </script>
</form>
```

This way the checkout is secured with **https**!

Now here's my warning about the plugin earlier mentioned. Thanks @Amrit Kahlon for updating that post!

---

Warning! **DO NOT** use the plugin discussed in this thread: [Telerik-Verified-Plugins/Stripe](http://plugins.telerik.com/plugin/stripe)

There doesn't seem to be a good alternative out there plugin-wise, you'll have to do it yourself as well it seems.

The plugin requires you to store your Stripe secret key on the client-side, which gives malicious people a chance to take it and use it.

The secret key is supposed to stay secret.

This is what the plugin's docs (https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/Stripe/blob/master/doc/index.md) say about itself:

> ### Security Warning
>
> This plugin requires that the Stripe secret key is embedded into the application. As the name suggests, you should never share the secret key as it allows full access to the Stripe API. Embedding the secret key into the application means that anyone can discover the key and use it to access the API. This could cause sensitive data to leak (all previous charges are visible) or even financial loss (refunds can be initiated).
>
> It is highly unlikely that you want to embed your Stripe secret key in a Cordova application, and hence highly unlikely you want to use this plugin.
>
> https://support.stripe.com/questions/difference-between-secret-key-and-publishable-key
>
> The correct method to accept payments from mobile devices uses the publishable key only. Whilst it is possible to submit payments using the secret key, anyone who obtains your secret key can view all prior charges, issue refunds, and initiate transfers.
>
> Please carefully consider if this is what is intended before use.

Comment: Actually you no longer need to use a plugin at all, checkout.js works. I'll update my answer