# Using Stripe Mobile Checkout in a WebView / Payments in Kik

Tags: stripe-payments, kik

I'm trying to implement Stripe Checkout for accepting mobile payments within the Kik Browser but unfortunately, I'm getting the following error when trying to load Checkout:

> Sorry, there was a problem loading Checkout. If this persists, please try a different browser.

Trying to create a custom form seems to work just fine - but I love the simple and intuitive design of Stripe's Mobile Checkout process - hence I'd prefer to use it, instead of building my own form.

Kik is using WebViews to display websites on both Android and iOS. I hope somebody from Stripe or Kik could weigh in on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Stripe Checkout only supports Chrome and Safari on iOS https://support.stripe.com/questions/browser-support-policy

Comment: We solve it this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37297962/stripe-checkout-not-working-in-android-webview/59198160#59198160

Answer (score 7):

This seems to do it for us:

```
<style> .stripe_checkout_app { height: 580px !important; } </style>
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: I've been told it's unsupported and recommended not to use it:

"We don't have plans to support WebView with Checkout in the near future. WebViews are fairly hard to support properly for our design, especially on Android where they vary widely in support for some functionalities and we feel like it wouldn't be a great experience for customer to have a degraded version of Checkout."

Comment: Thanks so much for this reply! This resolved my problem. I was struggling with a PWA because stripe was opening a separate browser tab, and when it redirected back to my PWA tab the app was restarted by the phone so I lost my progress. This managed to force Stripe to open a modal on mobile also, instead of a new screen.

Comment: adding the "mobile-web-app-capable" meta tag did the trick for me.