# Stripe checkout not working in android webview

Tags: android, webview, stripe-payments

I am working on android application. The server on which I am working gives the subscription feature to the users, so users need to do payment to become a member on the website.

Now I am working on the same in android app and using webview to perform the payment gateways. I am loading the url of stripe checkout payment in the webview.

But I am getting the below error for Stripe checkout in webview.

> Sorry, there was a problem loading Checkout. If this persists, please try a different browser.

How can I resolve this issue in the webview, so that it can work in my application?

Comment: webView?.settings?.javaScriptEnabled = true, is enough

Answer (score 24):

Stripe checkout indeed does not work on Android WebViews, but it does work on iOS UIWebView...
So... UserAgent comes to rescue!

```
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13E233 Safari/601.1");
```

Answer (score 6):

I have added this to the userAgent of the webview and it worked.
`"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; One Build/KTU84L.H4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/33.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/28.0.0.20.16;]"`

Comment: Thanks, Worked Fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Stripe Checkout doesn't support displaying Checkout in webviews. The best solution is to [build your own payment form](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms) using [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js).

Comment: How can I build the form for stripe gateway implementation and can use that in android webview.
Please guide if anyone how to do this.

Comment: @Ywain - that isn't really a helpful answer - why isn't it supported? What is the best way to deal with Stripe on Android?

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact technical reason, but knowing "why" wouldn't help: the point is that Checkout does not work in webviews on Android. It never has and AFAIK there are no plans to change this in the short term. If you're writing a web app / webview-based app, I already mentioned the "best" (only) solution: design your own form using Stripe.js. If you're writing a native app without webviews, you should use Stripe's Android SDK to collect and tokenize payment information instead.

Answer (score 0):

you problem is not with android device or android application, you have problem in your payment integration system.

if you are using Pay Now "Default popup for payment from stripe" it will surely occur an error. You need to integrate its payment system with your's own code by using AJAX token system.

Answer (score 0):

We also got the `"Sorry, there was a problem loading the Checkout. If this persists, please try a different browser."` error in WebView on Android (in React Native App)

After debugging the Stripe javascript, we found some code just for Android in WebView (see image below). By adding the tag `<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` the problem was solved for us. Now Stripe loads as on IOS.

[image: Stipe code]

Comment: Please,  don't post code as images. Posting it in textual form is more helpful for people looking for an answer.