# How to implement Stripe Payment Gateway in native android applications

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I am working on an android application. The server with which I am working give users to subscribe on the site and for that we implement payment gateways on our server.

The same payment gateways I want to implement in android application. We have worked for the below payment gateways:

**Paypal**

**2Checkout**

**Stripe**

I have implemented these gateways directly in webview and all the functionality work like website for Paypal and 2Checkout.

But Stripe is not working in webview and after exploring about stripe, I found that stripe does not support in mobile.

I have already scene the below link [Stripe checkout not working in android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37297962/stripe-checkout-not-working-in-android-webview/37304869#37304869) but I am not able to understand, that how can I implement stripe payment gateway in native android application.

Please help me if anyone know about this, this would be a great help.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: You need to build your own payment form using Stripe.js: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js and https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms or use Stripe's Android SDK: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android

Comment: Hi, Just a question about your 2checkout implementation. Did you use their js library on your webview?